# how to do Apache2 hosting for Jenkins Server

Tags: java, apache, jenkins

I am running jenkins on ubuntu server. I have installed this by apt-get install. I have install apache web server as well. Whenever I am opening mydomain.com it opening apache home page and when I am opening with mydomain.com:8080 it will open jenkins page. How I can set virtual hosting to open jenkins on mydomain.com I am very confused, I have 000.default.conf file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/. Please help to resolve this.

Comment: This seems like rather a broad question, have you tried searching for a tutorial? It helps to provide some idea of what you have tried yourself in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this situation is well documented and explained in the wiki link below

[Running Jenkins Behind Apache](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache)

Provide your comment if this helped. I would like to help you out further if this was not good enough for you

Comment: Yes thi sis with mod proxy, I want to do by simply virtual name hosting.